# Drop down menu linking issue with nested lists

Tags: html

I'm having issues with the drop down menu I created and linking to specific pages.

The issue I have is I cannot follow links to different pages as it tries to direct the browser to a file within the directory that doesn't exist. For example. When I am on the homepage and I drop down the ABOUT menu and hit OUR TEAM, it will direct to the OUR TEAM page, but once I am on the OUR TEAM page and drop down the RESOURCES menu, it tries to take me to "about/resources/whateverpage.php" as opposed to "/resources/whateverpage.php"

How do I make it so it will actually direct the to /resources directory instead of remaining within the /about directory. I've tried using "../" before the links but you can guess where the problems would arise with that.

As well, because of the fact that I have the links pointed to about/ourteam.php (for example), when I am in the ABOUT menu/directory and I go to click another page within the ABOUT menu it tries to lead me to about/about/hours.php instead of about/hours.php

Thanks folks.

My code is as follows:

```
<div id="menu">
          <ul><strong>
            <li><a href="index.php" accesskey="1" title="">HOME&nbsp; |</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" accesskey="2" title="">ABOUT&nbsp; |</a>
                   <ul>
                   <li><a href="about/ourteam.php">Our Team</a></li> 
                   <li><a href="about/referralprocess.php">Referral Process </a></li>
                   <li><a href="about/financialpolicy.php">Financial Policy</a></li>
                   <li><a href="about/facility.php">Facility</a></li>
                   <li><a href="about/hours.php">Hours/Directions</a></li>
                   </ul>
            </li>    
            <li><a href="#" accesskey="3" title="">EMERGENCY SERVICE &nbsp;|</a>
                   <ul>
                   <li><a href="emergencyservices/whatwedo.php">What We Do</a></li>
                   <li><a href="emergencyservices/howstaffed.php">How We Are Staffed</a></li>
                   <li><a href="emergencyservices/referralemerghandling.php">Emergency/Referral Procedure</a></li>
                   <li><a href="emergencyservices/typesofemerg.php">Types of Emergencies</a></li>
                   <li><a href="emergencyservices/whattoexpect.php">What to Expect On Arrival</a></li>
                   </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="specialtyservices.php" accesskey="4" title="">SPECIALTY SERVICE &nbsp;|</a>
                   <ul>
                   <li><a href="specialityservices/criticalcare.php">Critical Care</a></li>
                   <li><a href="specialityservices/internalmedicine.php">Internal Medicine</a></li>
                   <li><a href="specialityservices/surgery.php">Surgery</a></li>
                   <li><a href="specialityservices/rehab.php">Rehab</a><li>
                   </ul>
            </li>   
            <li><a href="resources.php" accesskey="5" title="">RESOURCES &nbsp;|</a>
                   <ul>
                   <li><a href="resources/forms.php">Referral Forms</a></li>
                   <li><a href="resources/reorder.php">Brochure/Business Card Reorder</a></li>
                   <li><a href="resources/emergtopics.php">Emergency Topics</a></li>
                   <li><a href="resources/criticalcaretopics.php">Critical Care Topics</a></li>
                   <li><a href="resources/internalmedicinetopics.php">Internal Medicine Topics</a></li>
                   <li><a href="resources/surgerytopics.php">Surgery Topics</a></li>
                   <li><a href="resources/rehabtopics.php">Rehab & Fitness Topics</a></li>
                   <li><a href="resources/links.php">Links</a></li>
                   <li><a href="resources/directions.php">Directions/Map</a></li>
                   <li><a href="resources/wheretostay.php">Where to Stay</a></li>
                   <li><a href="resources/newsletter.php">Newsletter</a></li>
                   </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="communityevents.php" accesskey="6" title="">COMMUNITY EVENTS &nbsp;|</a></li>
            <li><a href="careers.php" accesskey="7" title="">CAREERS &nbsp;|</a>
                   <ul>
                   <li><a href="careers/surgery.php">Surgery</a></li>
                   <li><a href="careers/neurosurgery.php">Neurosurgery</a></li>
                   <li><a href="careers/orthopaedic.php">Orthopaedic</a></li>
                   </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.php" accesskey="8" title="">CONTACT</a></li>

        </strong></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `/` to the front of your links.  These are relative links.

Comment: Nevermind, it didn't work when on my computer, but when uploaded to the server it worked perfect.  Thanks!